# Custom NbAuthStrategy getting result from async call

Tags: nebular, ngx-admin

I am creating my own authentication method. I have extended NbAuthStrategy and implemented method authenticate as shown below

```
@Injectable()
export class MyAuthStrategy extends NbAuthStrategy {
     ...
     authenticate(user: UserData): Observable<NbAuthResult> {
          ...
          this.userService.getUser(userId, function(user: IUser) {
              console.log("called back" + user); ////// ?????
          });
          ...
     }
     ...
}
```

the method is expected to return a Observable object.

When I do a memory authentication it works great, no issues.

The problem comes when I try to authenticate on an AWS Lambda by doing an async call. As the response is async, I cannot return Observable so I find this authentication mechanism only works for memory or synchronous calls.

How can I authenticate when validation is done on an async call?

Answer (score 0):

I got his working with the help provided here https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/2388

Basically:

1. return a Promise with the user from the AWS Lambda
2. wrap it an async await method so it returns another Promise
3. convert the Promise to Observable
4. pipe/map the Observable to return the Observable object

authenticate(user: UserData): Observable< NbAuthResult > {

```
   const userPromise: Promise<IUser> = this.userPromiseService.getUserPromise(user.schema, user.username);
   const userObservableDeferred3: Observable<NbAuthResult> = defer(() => userPromise)
     .pipe(
        map((res) => {

           return new NbAuthResult(
              true,
              null,
              '/pages/user-account',
             'Welcome',
           );

        }),
     );

   return userObservableDeferred3;
}

async getUserPromise(schema: string, username: string): Promise< IUser > {

  // invoke lambda
  const params = {
    ...
  };
  const result = await (this.getAWSLambda().invoke(params).promise());

  // get resulting user
  const payload = result.Payload;
  const arrayss = JSON.parse(payload);
  const array = JSON.parse(arrayss);
  const item = array[0];
  return < IUser >item;
}
```